# Minecraft Server scripts with screen and crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, java, cron, minecraft

Currently I am hosting my own minecraft server for my friends. I have created a "start.sh" and "backup.sh".
I would like my start script to run at boot, I would like it to start in a new screen using 'screen'

If it started in a new screen, my backup script is going to use a cron job so it can send commands to "mc" screen and stop it. So the backup script can run.

Only problems I have. I don't know how to do it. I have the script all set up, I just don't know how to use screen or crontab. Help?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Server

Comment: Hmmm. My favorite Search Engine showed me lots of tutorials about how to use `screen`. And about how to use `crontab`.  We are unlikely to reproduce those primers for you. Do you have any *specific* questions about usage?

Comment: @Cyruspapyrus Will do you need to stop the mc server for backup?

Comment: I need to stop the server every day for it to automatically update.